# Finding a sensible substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sin\varphi}{\cos^3\varphi}\, d\varphi$$

I think I need to use a substitution but I'm not sure what a sensible choice is.

Comment: Since $\sin\varphi$ is just the derivative of $-\cos\varphi$, the substitution $\varphi=\arccos(x)$ will work just fine.

Comment: It looks like the integrand is equal to $\tan\varphi \sec^2 \varphi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is best rewritten as

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{\sin\varphi}{\cos^3\varphi}\mathop{}\!d\varphi = \int_0^{\pi/4} \tan{\varphi}\ \sec^2{\varphi} \mathop{}\!d\varphi$$

Use $u = \tan\varphi \implies du=\sec^2{\varphi}\mathop{}\!d\varphi$ and change the boundary to get that

$$\int_0^{1} u \mathop{}\!du = \left[\frac{u^2}{2}\right]_0^{1} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int \frac{\sin x}{\cos^3x}dx=-\int\frac{d(\cos x)}{\cos^3x}=\frac1{2 
\cos^2x}+C$$

Then $$\int_0^{\frac\pi{4}} \frac{\sin x}{\cos^3x}dx=\frac{1}{2\cdot(\sqrt2/2)^2}-\frac12=1-\frac12=\frac12$$

Comment: @Joanpemo: Thank you! I edited!